# Computation of bernuli number

Tags: calculus, divisibility

Trying to follow the algorithm to [calculate Bernulli number](http://wstein.org/projects/168/kevin_mcgown/bernproj.pdf). On the page 4 it is written:

$$d = \prod_{p-1|m}p$$

which in my opinion means that I have to find all the numbers $p-1$ that divide $m$ and then multiplies all these $p$.

But on the page 5 for the example of $m=50$ they calculate something strange: d = 2 * 3 * 11. This is strange because 50 has 5 divisors (without 1) and they only multiply 3 numbers. Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compute the product of all primes $p$ with $(p-1) | 50$ and these are $2,3,11$. Or the other way round: look for the proper divisiors $q$ of $50$ with $q+1$ prime; cf. the section [von Staudt - Clausen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Von_Staudt.E2.80.93Clausen_theorem) with $m=2n$.